# Solving the congruence $7x \equiv 41 \mod{13}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations

I have to solve the following linear congruence:

$$7x \equiv 41 \mod{13}$$

The question where I got this from comes in two parts. The first is that it asks to find the set of the inverses of $7 \mod 13$, which turns out to be $[2]_{13}$ but, I found that solution by solving the linear diophantine equation $$7x - 13k - 41$$ which is just the original equation in disguise i.e. $7x \equiv 41 \mod{13}$.

Now, I'm terribly confused as to the solution of the congruence equation. Where am I going wrong and how should I proceed?

Thanks!

EDIT: From @Bill's hint

\begin{align}
7x &\equiv 41 \mod{13} \\
x &\equiv \frac{41}{7} \mod{13} \\
x &\equiv \frac{28}{7} \mod{13} \quad (?) \\
x &\equiv 4 \mod{13} \\
\end{align}

Then, this gives me the solution $[4]_{13}$.

Comment: That $2$ is the inverse of $7$ is clear, now multiply through by $2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reduce the congruence to $7x \equiv 2$. Since $\gcd(7,13) = 1$, there exists a unique inverse of $7$ modulo $13$. Note that the inverse is just $2$ since $7 \cdot 2 \equiv 1 \pmod {13}$. Then it follows that $(7)(7^{-1})x \equiv x \equiv 2(7^{-1}) \equiv 4 \pmod {13}$ and that is the solution set.

Comment: How did you arrive at $7x \equiv 2$? Is that because of $[2]_{13}$? Also, I'm confused with your last two sentences, can you please clarify more?

Comment: From $41 \equiv 2$. A general tip is to always reduce the residue $r$ to $0 \le r \le p-1$ when taking modulo $p$. Then another property of modular arithmetic is that we define the inverse of $r$ mod $p$ as $r^{-1}$ such that $r \cdot r^{-1} \equiv 1$. Then, we must multiply by the inverse for both sides.

Comment: ahhh! I think I'm getting it now. Thanks!

Comment: @gek This can be considered a special case of Gauss's algorithm - see my answer for a link to that.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** $\ {\rm  mod}\ 13\!:\  \dfrac{41}7 \equiv  \dfrac{28}7 = 4\ \ $ by $\ \ 41\equiv 41\!-\!13 = 28$

**Alternatively** $\ \dfrac{41}{7}\equiv\dfrac{(-2)(-1)}{-6}\equiv \dfrac{-2}{-2}\dfrac{12}3\equiv 4\ \ $ by $\ \ \begin{eqnarray}41&&\equiv\ \ 2\\ 7 &&\equiv -6\end{eqnarray}$

**Alternatively** $\ \dfrac{41}{7}\equiv \dfrac{2}7\equiv \dfrac{4}{14}\equiv \dfrac{4}1\ $ by [Gauss's Algorithm.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242)

Such twiddling (adding/subtracting the modulus from numerator or denominator till things divide or factor nicely) works quite well for small numbers (more generally we can use [Inverse Reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) to make the quotient exact. For larger numbers one can invert the denominator by the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242), or [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) if the modulus is prime.

**Beware** $\ $ The use of fractions in modular arithmetic is valid only when the denominator is invertible, i.e. coprime to the modulus. Otherwise the quotient need not be unique, for example mod $\rm\:10,\:$ $\rm\:4\,x\equiv 2\:$ has solutions $\rm\:x\equiv 3,8,\:$ so the "fraction" $\rm\:x \equiv 2/4\pmod{10}\,$ cannot designate a unique solution of $\,4x\equiv 2.\,$ Indeed, the solution is $\rm\:x\equiv 1/2\equiv 3\pmod 5,\,$ which requires canceling $\,2\,$ from the *modulus* too, since $\rm\:10\:|\:4x-2\iff5\:|\:2x-1.\:$

Generally the grade-school rules of fraction arithmetic apply *universally* (i.e. in all rings) where the denominators are invertible. This fundamental property will be clarified conceptually when one learns in university algebra about the *universal properties* of fractions rings and localizations.

Comment: This may be a stupid question but how do you arrive at this hint? Please, see my edit.

Comment: Add or subtract the modulus from the numerator or denominator till you get numbers that divide or factor nicely. Such twiddling works well for *small* numbers. For bigger ones use brute-force inversion algorithms such as the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Comment: That last edit was very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$\tag{1}  7 x - 13k = 41$$

Let $a = x - 2k$, so $$\tag{2}x = a + 2k$$.

Substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$: $$7(a + 2k) - 13k = 41$$
$$7a + k = 41$$
$$k = 41 - 7a \tag{3}$$

Substituting $(3)$ into $(2)$:  $$x = a + 2(41 - 7a)$$
$$x = 82 - 13a$$
Plug any integer you like into $a$, and out pops a valid $x$.

Answer (score 0):

The OP states

> ... but, I found that solution by solving the linear diophantine equation

From this [site](http://gauss.math.luc.edu/greicius/Math201/Fall2012/Lectures/linear-congruences.article.pdf) I found

[image]

Here the equation is $7x\equiv 41 \pmod {13}$ or

$$\tag 1 7x\equiv 2 \pmod {13}$$

Here also, multiplication $7 \times x$ is repeated addition. So you can also get the inverse of ${[7]_{13}}^{-1}$ and/or the solution of $\text{(1)}$ using the same technique (might as well cycle through it all):

$\quad 7 \times 1 \equiv 0 + 7 \equiv 7 $
$\quad 7 \times 2 \equiv 7 + 7 \equiv 1 $
$\quad 7 \times 3 \equiv 1 + 7 \equiv 8 $
$\quad 7 \times 4 \equiv 8 + 7 \equiv 2 $
$\quad 7 \times 5 \equiv 2 + 7 \equiv 9 $
$\quad 7 \times 6 \equiv 9 + 7 \equiv 3 $
$\quad 7 \times 7 \equiv 3 + 7 \equiv 10$
$\quad 7 \times 8 \equiv 10 + 7 \equiv 4$
$\quad 7 \times 9 \equiv 4 + 7 \equiv 11$
$\quad 7 \times 10 \equiv 11 + 7 \equiv 5$
$\quad 7 \times 11 \equiv 5 + 7 \equiv 12$
$\quad 7 \times 12 \equiv 12 + 7 \equiv 6$
$\quad 7 \times 13 \equiv 6 + 7 \equiv 0 $

Looking over your work you can pick out both the inverse and the solution.

You can set up a spreadsheet to handle these problems and/or check your work.